# How to prove for any arbitrary area its component along the direction of electric field is Acosx?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

Consider electric flux we write it as $A$ times cosine of angle made by the area vector and the electric field and we say that it is only component of area perpendicular to electric field that is responsible for flux.

My question is if area is a vector such that its magnitude represents the area of the surface and its direction perpendicular to surface then how can we prove that projection of area vector along electric field results into an area of magnitude $A \cos(x)$ where $A$ is original area and $x$ is angle between electric field $E$ and $A$ for any kind of irregular surface or circular surface it an be easily proved for a rectangle as in University Physics book but what about rest?

Comment: Is $x$ the angle between the planar area snd the electric field or the normal to the planar area and the electric field. They mean two _different_ things.

Comment: Between normal and E

Comment: Any arbitrary area can be thought of as collection of large number of small rectangle areas. Its basically it is integration over the surface.